# Access VPN through the proxy

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, proxy

I have a MacOS laptop that is connected to the VPN.

My final goal is to have access to everything behind the VPN from my linux laptop. Both laptops are connected to the same wifi network.

I tried to just get internet access from linux machine (VPN disconnected yet). First I thought it can be done via route table, so I setup the default route to macos address:

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via 192.168.0.20
```

But for some reason it didn't work. Then I thought about setting `http_proxy=192.168.0.20` with no luck.

**What should I do to be able to connect to the internet through macos machine on the same network?**

[image]

EDIT:

I tried to investigate it with `traceroute` and it looks like there is the hop from macos to the router, but then for some reason connection is lost...

```
root@fifek:/home/kosciej# traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.203.142), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.0.20  13,497ms  4,681ms  4,888ms
  2   192.168.0.1  12,943ms  11,999ms  8,238ms
  3   *  *  *
  4   *  *  *
```

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/459499/access-vpn-through-the-proxy

Comment: Adding a route is not enough. Let me know if the method described in [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/share-macs-internet-connection-using-os-x/) for sharing your Mac’s internet connection can help.

Comment: I went through it and it's not what I am searching for. My mac machine needs to be connected via wifi, bluetooth will be to slow, my sharing options are "controlled by profile" so I cannot even change them in graphical way and one of the goal is to understand it. Do you know why adding a route is not enough and what such "sharing" actually does under the hood?

Comment: @harrymc from what I read routing + enable forwarding should be enough (I did the last with `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`)

Comment: The article describes connecting to internet via ethernet cable, then sharing it via wifi. This procedure would create a wifi hotspot. There are two methods described, where only the second is for bluetooth (your case is the first one). Does this fit your needs?

Comment: @harrymc please, see my comment above. I updated the question with additional info if it helps anyhow